# How to extract only version number from string

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract the 4th number from this text format `xx.xx.xx.xx` for example `(7.0.3.10)` so I used this

```
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(applicationVersion, r'[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*\.([^.]*)'
```

But sometimes the last argument is a string and not number, like this `7.0.10.1_chargable` and I'm trying to find a way to ignore the arguments after the number, so I will get `1`

```
 SELECT
      

     REGEXP_EXTRACT(applicationVersion, r'[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*\.([^.]*)') ,
     applicationVersion,
     max(eventTimestamp)

         FROM
      `datascience.AppEvents`

     group by 1,2 order by 2 desc
```

[image]

**What do I need to change for getting this result?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the regex pattern `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.(\d+)`:

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(applicationVersion, r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.(\d+)'),
    applicationVersion,
    MAX(eventTimestamp)
FROM datascience.AppEvents
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
(?:[0-9]+\.){3}([0-9]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zEzpC2/1). *Details*:

- `(?:[0-9]+\.){3}` - three occurrences of one or more digits and then a dot
- `([0-9]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

> to extract the 4th number from this text format xx.xx.xx.xx

You can use below

```
regexp_extract_all(applicationVersion, r'\d+')[safe_offset(3)]
```